# The template function encountered an error when passed in a numeric literal, but string literals didn't

Tags: c++, string, templates, literals

I'm writing this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


template <typename T>
void Print(T& value)
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Print("Hello");
    Print(1);
}
```

And when compiling, compilers told an error that “`void Print<int>(T &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'T &'`". But the `Print("Hello")` didn't get an error. Why is that?

And I changed `Print()` function to

```
void Print(T value)
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

It worked. But I don't understand why the former code didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Case 1

Here we consider how `Print(1);` works.

In this case, the **problem** is that `1` is an **rvalue** and you're trying to bind that rvalue to a **lvalue reference to nonconst `T`**( that is, `T&`) which is not possible and hence the error. For example you cannot have:

```
void Print(int &value)
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   Print(1);// won't work
}
```

##### Solution

So to **solve** your problem you can use a **lvalue reference to const `T`**(that is `const T&`) that can be bind to an rvalue, as shown below:

```
template <typename T>
void Print(const T& value)//note the const added here
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
   
    Print(1); //works now
}
```

Alternatively, you can also make the parameter as a **rvalue reference to nonconst `T`**(that is `T&&`).

```
template <typename T>
void Print(T&& value)//note the && added here
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
   
    Print(1); //this works too
}
```

##### Case 2

Here we consider the statement `Print("Hello");`

In this case, `"Hello"` is a [**string literal**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) and has the type `const char [6]`. Also, the string literal `"Hello"` is an **lvalue**.

And we know that we can bind an lvalue to a **lvalue reference to nonconst `T`**(that is `T&`). So there is no error in this case. Also note that in this case the `T` is deduced to be `const char [6]`.

#### Note

In case 2 above (`Print("Hello");`) there is **no type decay** because the argument is passed by reference and not by value.

Answer (score 2):

`1` is an *rvalue*, and so cannot bind to `T&`. It *can* bind to `const T&` though.

That is,

```
void Print(const T& value)
```

or

```
void Print(T&& value)
```

are the fixes.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Because of this:

```
test.cpp:45:11: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'int&' to an rvalue of type 'int'
   45 |     Print(1);
      |           ^
```

So convert it to a universal reference:

```
template <typename T>
void Print( T&& value ) // notice &&, that's a universal reference, not an rvalue ref
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Nicked your binding. Have an upvote for good feelings ;-)